# How do I start mariadb without the option --skip-grant-tables?

Tags: mariadb

I'm installing mariadb on a fresh install of ubuntu 24.04 from the default repo's.

After installation, I run 'mysql_secure_installation'.
The first question I'm asked is the root password for mysql.

My understanding is that by default there is no root mysql password.

When I hit 'return', I get the message:

```
Error 1290 (HY000) at line 1: The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

How can I start mariaDB without this option?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve:

```
Error 1290 (HY000) at line 1: The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Find `skip-grant-tables` in your configuation file. If you run `sudo -u mariadbd --help --verbose` the files it reads is at the top of the output.

If nothing is there shutdown the `mariadbd` process (`sudo killall mariadbd`) and then start the server normally like `systemctl start mariadb.service`.

The default Ubuntu package install is with a secure [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security) authentication for the root user.

If you'd like to set a password for the root user as well (and make it less secure, passwords can be used by any unix user):

```
sudo mariadb -e 'set password = password("my secure password")'
```

Running `mysql_secure_installation` isn't required (and needs a lot of work).